# in a textbox or richtextbox, how can i remove enclosing text brackets when clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

Consider that the given text in a ritchTextbox be

```
Have [a wonderful] [day]!
```

When i click "a wonderful", how can i remove the enclosing bracket ?

Results in:

```
Have a wonderful [day]!
```

Comment: Do you mean you just want to change the text from "Have a wonderful [day]!" to "Have a wonderful day!"? Or do you mean *replace*, such as that it would be today: "Have a wonderful Tuesday!"? If you want to remove the brackets from around [a wonderful], you need to determine that the cursor is over those words. It's not as easy as you might think. Doable? Yes, but not a one-liner.

Comment: Not sure if you are using winforms or web.  That'll determine whether you do this in C# or Javascript.  Either way, you'll need to grab the string and replace the elements to your liking with string manipulation.

Comment: OK, what about this string `have [a [wonderful] [day]]`? You may end up removing 2 sets of brackets when you click on "day"

Comment: I am using winforms. i just need to remove the first enclosing bracket when i click the word within it.  In my sample i just want it to show "Have a wonderful [day]!

Answer (score 2):

For a TextBox or RichTextBox add the following to the Click event:

```
        int SelectionStart = this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart - 1;
        if (SelectionStart > 0)
        {
            string Text = this.richTextBox1.Text;
            int Start = Text.LastIndexOf('[', SelectionStart);
            int End = Text.IndexOf(']', SelectionStart);
            int OtherStart = Text.LastIndexOf(']', SelectionStart);
            int OtherEnd = Text.IndexOf('[', SelectionStart);
            if (Start > -1 && End > -1 && (OtherStart < 0 || OtherStart < Start) && (OtherEnd < 0 || OtherEnd > End))
            {
                this.richTextBox1.Text = Text.Remove(Start, 1).Remove(End - 1, 1);
            }
        }
```